# parseToElement is not working in XMLWorkerHelper class

Tags: java, itext

```
public static final String[] HTML="D:/testing.htm","D:/testing.htm","D:/testing.htm","D:/testing.htm"};
public static final String DEST = ""D:/multiple_html_pages2.pdf";

            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
                File file = new File(DEST);
                file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                new ParseMultipleHtmlFiles2().createPdf(DEST);
            }


            public void createPdf(String file) throws IOException, DocumentException {
                Document document = new Document();
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
                document.open();

                for (String htmlfile : HTML) {
                    String html = Utilities.readFileToString(htmlfile);
// parsing error are showing there : 

                    ElementList list = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(htmlfile);



                    for (com.itextpdf.text.Element e : list) {
                        document.add(e);
                    }
                    document.newPage();
                }
                document.close();
            }
```

Comment: Should we guess what error message you get?

Comment: The method parseToElementList(String) is undefined for the type XMLWorkerHelper

Comment: from which package you Import the class?

Comment: import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper

Comment: There no method with Name `parseToElementList` in this class. where you find this code?

Comment: this website:http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker-itext5/html-tables

Comment: how to create single pdf of multiple html pages

Comment: Which Version of itext do you have in your classpath

Comment: i have used the itext 2.1.5 version and xmlworker 5.4.2

Comment: I guess the method is introduced in a later Version. on the site you have the code, there is itext5 and itext7 downloadable. You should do it and ad the jar files to your classpath

Comment: iText 2.x.x is no longer supported and Xmlworker 5.x.y was never meant to work together with it anyway.
I also downvoted the question because you only provided code and had us guess to both what exception you were getting and to what versions of iText you are using. Please include these in your questions whenever you post them.

Comment: You have to use the same version of iText and XMLWorker.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, you write:

*I have used the itext 2.1.5 version and xmlworker 5.4.2*

That combination can never work. XML Worker was introduced much later than iText 2.1.5. iText 2.1.5 dates from March 2009, whereas XML Worker 5.4.2 dates from May 2013.

You need to use an iText version of which the number corresponds with the XML Worker version number.